# Cannot read property 'parameters' of undefined while passing Context - Actions on Google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Currently I am trying to develop an action.

I am trying to achieve to reuse an intent. Concretely said, it means that the Assistant shall give me the first three items of a list and if I ask for more, then it should give me the next three items of the list.

I implemented the logic, which is locally working but sadly I always got the first three items from the list. Therefore i tried using a context, where I want to pass the index as a parameter and here i am running into the problem. The cloud function logs always gives me:

> Cannot read property 'parameters' of undefined.

I am using dialog v2 api and the actions on Google sdk. Following link provides an example how to implement the context and I don't see a big difference there. https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejsv2/overview

The code written for it looks like this:

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
    conv.ask('Welcome.')

    const lifespan = 100;
    const parameters = {
        index: 0,
    };
    conv.contexts.set('movieCtx', lifespan, parameters);
});

app.intent('New Cinema Movies Intent', async conv => {
    let movieCtx = conv.contexts.get('movieCtx');
    let index = movieCtx.parameters[index]

    let movieRepository = new MovieRepository();
    movieRepository.index = index;
    await movieRepository.fetchNextTitle(3).then(function(titles) {
        movieCtx.parameters[index] = movieRepository.index;
        conv.ask('The 3 movies are:' + titles.join(', '))

        return true;
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err); 
        return false;
    });
})
```

My dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.5.0",
    "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.3",
    "pg": "^7.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**Update:**

I also tried to change the following lines but also that couldn't help me:

```
const parameters = {
        movieIndex: 0,
};

let index = movieCtx.parameters['movieIndex']
```

Comment: it should be conv.contexts.get('movieCtx')

Comment: Thanks for that! That is actually true and i corrected it but still not working though :(

Comment: and this line too     let index = movieCtx.parameters.index

Comment: I tried that too but still getting the same error. If i am simulating the action i get following error:

Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response.

The cloud function gives me the parameter error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer!

```
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const MovieRepository = require('./PostgreSQL/MovieRepository');
let movieRepository = new MovieRepository();

const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

const AppContexts = {
    NUMBER: 'number',
}

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
    const lifespan = 10;
    const parameters = {
        movieIndex: 0,
    };
    conv.contexts.set(AppContexts.NUMBER, lifespan, parameters);
    conv.ask('Welcome!')
});

app.intent('New Cinema Movies Intent', async (conv) => {
    const movieCtx = conv.contexts.get(AppContexts.NUMBER);

    await movieRepository.fetchNextTitle(3).then(function(titles) {
        movieCtx.parameters.movieIndex = movieRepository.index;
        conv.ask('The 3 movie titles are: ' + titles.join(', '));
        return true;
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err); 
        return false;
    });
})

app.intent('Default Fallback Intent', conv => {
    conv.ask('Sorry. Can you repeat?')
})

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

As you can see you have to create the AppContext above the intents. Somhow weird but important is that you apply

```
NUMBER: 'number'
```

to the context, otherwise you get an undefined context again. And to access your parameters you just need to append your the value of your parameter like this:

```
movieCtx.parameters.movieIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
let index = movieCtx.parameters[index]
```

Should probably be

```
let index = movieCtx.parameters['index']
```

(You don't have `index` defined previous to that, so it is trying to get the reference of undefined, which isn't valid.)

Comment: Hey Prisoner, thanks for the answer! 
Sadly that didn't worked for me.
I also tried to do the following:
`const parameters = {
        movieIndex: 0,
};`
and then changed the line to:
`let index = movieCtx.parameters['movieIndex'];`

Also that could not help me.

Comment: Please don't show code in comments. If you've changed code, add it to the original question.